# Odoo 16 POS CE Payment Method Challenge

Tags: windows-ce, accounting, odoo-16

I am in a challenge where I must setup Odoo 16 community POS for a client who is having a restaurant accepting payments as “Cash, Credit Cards, and Orders coming from delivery applications”

Now it is easy to setup cash and credit cards as payment methods in POS but the challenge is coming with Orders Applications.

| Payment Method | Related to Journal | Journal Type | CoA Type | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cash | Cash | Cash | Bank & Cash | Working Fine |
| Credit Cards | CC | Bank | Bank & Cash | Working Fine |
| Delivery Applications | Delivery Apps | Sales | Receivables | Here is the challenge! Below is the comment |

Now I want to setup the Delivery Apps as Sales under receivable account and whenever I change Journal type to “Sales” and account type to “Receivable” I will not be able to assign it to “Delivery Applications” at all. In fact, it will not show at all.

How Delivery Applications work? Customer will pick all the items he wants from his favorite delivery app and then I get that order on a specific handheld device I have in the restaurant. This app will not pay me until end of each month. Therefore, I cannot consider this sale as “Income”… it can be considered only as “Sale” and should be receivables until the app pay me end of the month to reconcile it and consider it as income.

Does anyone have idea or workaround for this issue?

Comment: This is a "Commission" system, where users earn a certain amount of money for each sale, based on the product or service they sell to the customer.